# The count() method counts wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my task to solve.

For a list of integers, find and print the items that appear in the list
only once. Items must be printed in the order in which they are
are in the incoming list.

I wrote the code but it also counts two and three digit numbers as a single digits. What's the problem?

```
x = []
a = input()
a.split(" ")
for i in a:
    if a.count(i) == 1:
        x.append(i)
print(x)
```

Comment: provide some sample input and outputs!

Comment: You forget assignment, try `a = a.split(' ')`.

Comment: print out intermediate results (e.g. `i` at every step) to get an insight of what happens

Comment: Check the value of `i` for each iteraion. You are looping in a string nor a list.

Answer (score 1):

User Mechanical Pig provides the answer, `split` does not work in-place, since you're discarding its result what you're looking at is the count of each character in the string, not each space-separated sub-string.

The standard library also contains a collection which is ready-made for this use-case: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). You can just give it a sequence of items and it'll collate the counts, which you can then filter:

```py
print([k for k, v in collections.Counter(a.split()).items() if v == 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.split(" ")` does not change the value of `a`, so it is still a string and not a list. Hence when you iterate over `a`, you only get single characters.

`str.split` is a method that **returns** a list, but does not magically turn the string into a list. So you need to assign the value it returns to a variable (for example, to `a`, if you don't want to hold on to the input string).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the variable as mentioned above or you can directly use the split function in the loop.

```
x = []
a = input()
for i in a.split(" "):
    if a.count(i) == 1:
        x.append(i)
print(x)
```

or split when you are reading the input.

```
x = []
a = input().split(" ")
for i in a:
    if a.count(i) == 1:
        x.append(i)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Counter class from the *collections* module is the right way to do this but here's another way without any imports where you effectively have your own limited implementation of a Counter:

```
a = '1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 7'

d = {}

for n in a.split():
    d[n] = d.get(n, 0) + 1

for k, v in d.items():
    if v == 1:
        print(k)
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
5
6
```